# Shopify Email templates add barcode (UPC)

Tags: html, email, templates, shopify

In shopify admin panel ( settings > notifications > Email templates )
it allows you to edit the email sent to my distributor with order information on it like : address, price and the SKU to send that customer. I am trying to add the Barcode UPC to the email template as well.

This is the .liquid code for the SKU

```
 (sku: {{ line.sku }})
```

Here is a link to the email variable reference guide but I cant find one for the barcode, any ideas?

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/notifications/email-variables

Comment: You can inject custom attributes but I don't believe they can be images.

Comment: Oh sorry, not the actual barcode, but just the upc #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the upc in an unused product field (e.g. vendor) and then output this field in your email template {{ line.vendor }}.

If there are no unused fields available then you can store the upc in a metafield and output this metafield in your email template:

```
{{line.product.metafields.some_namespace.your_key}}
```

Here is the documentation for metafields: [metafields](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/metafield)

Where is the upc currently stored?

Answer (score 2):

Shopify customer support answered my question.
{{ line.variant.barcode }}

Answer (score 1):

So, one of the options would be to set a cart attribute, which you could then output in the email.

Here's a link to setting cart attributes, but in your case you'd probably want the input to be hidden (since the customer doesn't need to type anything in).

It's a bit of a hack, but the alternative is using an app with a webhook to generate a UPC and send it.

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/communicating-with-customers/obtain-information/ask-customer-for-more-information

Comment: Very creative solution, definitely my fall back option if I cant get this going the way I want.